# Vue JS - Vuetify Snackbar not firing when coming back from another view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have implemented a Vuetify Snackbar with two ways to fire it.
a) using a button (just for debug purposes)
b) using a method, showUserMessage, which simply sets showNotification=true

The user can then click the button in the snackbar and visit a different view.

```js
div class="text-center">
  <v-btn
        dark
        @click="showNotification = true"
      >
        Open Snackbar
      </v-btn>
      <v-snackbar
        v-model="showNotification"
        timeout=0
        min-width=480
        absolute top
        class="white--text"
        color="purple darken-2"
        text
      >
        {{ notificationMessage }}
  
        <template v-slot:action="{ attrs }">
          <v-btn
          dark
            color="pink darken-2"
            v-bind="attrs"
            @click="GoToSession()"
          >
            Start session
          </v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-snackbar>
    </div>
```

The GotSoSession method:

```js
      GoToSession() {
          this.showNotification=false
          this.$router.push({path: '/'}); 
      },
```

Both the button and showUserMessage call trigger the display of the snackbar. Clicking the 'Start session' button (calling GoToSession) visits the new view as expected.

However, when I return to this page, clicking the button again displays the snackbar, but a call to the showUserMessage method fails to display it, even though I can see it sets showNotification=true. It will not display it until I reload the page.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Thanks Wakeel. Here is more context:

```js
    this.$pnGetMessage('ch1', this.showUserMessage);


    showUserMessage(msg) {
       this.notificationMessage = msg.message.text
       this.showNotification=true   
       console.log("showNotification:" + this.showNotification)
    }
```

I am not sure how to implement the suggestions you make below, could you provide an example based on the $pnGetMessage call above?

Comment: Where is showUserMessage called?

Comment: showUserMessage is called from a pub/sub callback. It is defined in the list of functions()  showUserMessage(msg) {
        console.log("received message.....")
        this.notificationMessage = msg.message.text
          this.showNotification=true   
          console.log("showNotification:" + this.showNotification)
      }

Comment: I can see that the function is called and that showNotification is set to true

Answer (score 1):

It could be as a result of the context in which the function is called.

**Option 1**: Try bind the function passed to the subscription

```
  theSubFunction(this.showUserMessage.bind(this));
```

**Options 2**: Pass an arrow function that receives the message from the sub and calls `showUserMessage`

```
  theSubFunction((message)=>{
      this.showMessage(message);
  });
```

Comment: Hi Wakeel. I have edited in a bit more detail above, thanks

Comment: this.$pnGetMessage('ch1', (message)=>{
      this.showMessage(message);
  });

Comment: Thanks for the sample, the code works, but I get the same issue! The callback displays the Snackbar, until I visit another page, then go back. At this point the callback is still firing (I can see console messages) but the Vuetify Snackbar is not opening. If I hit the button, it does display.

Comment: Remove the timeout property and try again.

Comment: same result. Is there something in the Vue lifecycle i can call to reset this so it looks like it is a page refresh? Refreshing the page removes the issue and the callback starts to work again.

Comment: I'm surprised it's not working. It's hard to debug when there is no way to tes4 or view code for the whole component.

Comment: You can try this.$nextTick

Comment: In your showUserMessage function, add: this.$nextTick(() => this.showNotification = true );

Comment: Also try in GoToSession() {
          this.showNotification=false;
          this.$nextTick(() => this.$router.push({path: '/'})); 
      },

Comment: Hi Wakeel. Tried both suggestions and still no success. Really appreciate your support here and that is is constrained by not having all the code. I have other options (e.g. use the vue-toasted component), so will try them instead. Thanks again.